# How change the margin only in on class of a tag in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

My code is like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-6"></div>
```

I want to add margin-top:-30px; only when div use col-xs-12. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target just the "xs" class via a media query. If you want to target only that particular div I would add another class to it. Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<div class="sample-class col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-6"></div>
```

CSS:

```
@media(max-width:767px){
.sample-class {
    margin-top:-30px;
   }
}
```